# Get parent of Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I have a `Binding` object and I want to know parent of this `Binding`.

Example:

```
<Label Name="BindingLabel" Content="{Binding Path=LabelText}"/>
```

In example parent of `Binding` is `Label` with name **BindingLabel** and I search way to get it only from `Binding` object.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A [`Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx) can be used on multiple objects, so it can't have a single `Parent`. If you know what objects you're looking through (e.g. you already have a list, or you can walk a tree) and what dependency properties to check, you can check if the element uses that binding.

Here's how you can do that if you have the exact instance of `Binding` that's used:

```
Binding binding = // whatever (must be the same instance used in the object)
IEnumerable<Label> labels = // whatever
foreach (var label in labels)
{
    if (label.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty).ParentBinding
        == binding)
    {
        // found it!
    }
}
```

Or maybe you just want to compare the path:

```
var path = "LabelText";
IEnumerable<Label> labels = // whatever
foreach (var label in labels)
{
    if (label.GetBindingExpression(Label.ContentProperty).ParentBinding.Path.Path
        == path)
    {
        // found it!
    }
}
```

Comment: I do it such way now, but I'm looking way to find without knowing all objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is kindof vague because you don't describe what you intent to do with it. If you want to set a particular property of the label you could use a valueconverter. Additionally you can pass in a reference to the object itself by using RelativeSource=Self in a (multi)binding

```
<Label> 
   <Label.Content> 
      <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource MyConverter}"> 
          <MultiBinding.Bindings> 
             <Binding Path="LabelText" /> 
             <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/> 
          </MultiBinding.Bindings> 
       </MultiBinding> 
   </Label.Content> 
</Label>
```

i didn't tested the code so i might be off with the binding declaration or something.